# what does >& mean in a shell command?

Tags: shell-script, shell

I actually have 2 questions:

1. What does `>&` mean in a shell script as in `/usr/bin/x_app >& /tmp/blog.txt`? Shouldn't a number follows `&` to make it a stdout/err thing?
2. As far as I know that `>` is overwriting and `>>` is appending, so `2>&1` should just replace stdout with stderr, but instead, it means putting stdout and stderr together. 
   Why don't we use `>>`? I mean I know "appending" does not mean "putting them together" either but it's closer to it than "overwriting", right?

Comment: For the 2nd question: `2>&1` means just `dup2(1, 2)` and is *absolutely the same as* `2<&1`. After it, the `2` and `1` fds can be used interchangeably. Don't try to read to much into; the only difference between `<&` and `>&` is what fd is the default on the left side when not specified (`0` vs `1`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`>& file` is a csh operator (from the late 70s) to redirect both stdout and stderr to `file`. The Bourne shell (also from the late 70s) equivalent is `> file 2>&1`, or `2> file >&1`, that is redirect fd 1 to `file` and then fd 2 to the same *open file description* or vice versa.

`zsh` and `bash` are two shells (from the late 80s, early 90s) that took features from both the Korn¹ shell (and by extension the Bourne shell) and csh, and support that `>&` csh operator in addition to the `[i]>&j` Bourne/Korn operator.

Those two conflicts though.

```
cmd >& "$var"
```

Will end up doing the Bourne/Korn redirection if `$var` contains a number and the csh one otherwise.

In practice, it's better to avoid that csh operator and use the Bourne syntax instead (`cmd > "$var2" 2>&1`) in those shells to avoid surprises.

Note that initially, `bash` didn't support csh's `>&` but had `&>` instead for the same feature. That also conflicted with Bourne syntax. In the Bourne shell, `cmd &> file` is `cmd` and `> file` run in parallel. `zsh` also added support for `&>` latter for compatibility with `bash`.

You'll find yet different syntax in different shells. In `rc` (late 80s) and derivatives (`es`, `akanga`), Bourne's `2>&1` is written `>[2=1]` (and it makes it easier to specify which fds are to be at each end of pipes: `cmd1 |[3=4] cmd2` (connecting fd 3 of `cmd1` to fd 4 of `cmd2` via a pipe) which in Bourne syntax, you'd need to write `{ cmd1 3>&1 >&5 5>&- | 4<&0 <&6 6<&- cmd2; } 5>&1 6<&0`).

The `fish` shell (mid 2000s) has different variations in [I/O redirection syntax](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#redirects)  from the Bourne shell's.

---

<sup>¹ The Korn shell (from the early 80s) was based on the Bourne shell but also borrowed features from csh like aliases, tilde expansion and brace expansion.</sup>